# Shortkeys alternative for for the Linux console/terminal?

Tags: linux, console

Some years ago there was a tool called ShortKeys which I used a lot (https://www.shortkeys.com/). The tool replaces given keystrokes with other ones, or even with full text strings (inc multiple lines) etc.

So for example one would type `#GB` and `#GB` would be erased and instead it would type `God Bless` in place of what was there, automatically.

It would be great to have such a tool for Linux. Are you aware of any?

My main use would be console/terminal-based. So for example, working in `vi` I would type some specific keys which are picked up by some tool and auto-replaced by a specially desired text.

If `vi` can do something like this natively, that would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vi` has the option to us abbreviations. In `vi`, type

```
:ab hop hoppa, klap, klap
```

Type `hop` as a single word (end with space)in

There is a package called `autokey`, which should be able to do comparable things to what you ask. Never used it tohough.

Comment: Thank you very much. `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk` was all it took. Super. And I assume the vi shortcuts can somehow be included in `~/.vimrc` ?

Comment: [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) has no Wayland support.